# Unblock-UI Not working In Mozilla and IE-11

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have added block UI in My project here is the code which I am using

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    data: "",
    url: "<?php echo SITE_SCRIPT_PATH;?>get_dashboard_tiles",
    beforeSend: function () {
        $(".right_con").css("min-height", "300px").block();
        $(".blockOverlay").css("background-color", "");
        $(".right_con").unblock();
    },
    complete: function () {
        $(".right_con").unblock();

    },
    success: function (r) {
        $("#box_set").append(r);
        render_dashboard_tiles();
        lazyLoadTiles();
    }
  });
```

In all browser excepting IE-11 and Mozilla the unblock-UI is not working. even it is not coming in completed block, so any one can suggest me where I am wrong

Comment: do some formatting to your code. I have done it for you this time.

Comment: Thanks But this is my first so..any way thx and please suggest me

Comment: check this out http://malsup.com/jquery/block/#overview

Comment: Done with that as well but not working..

Answer (score 0):

This should be done this way:

```
$.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   data: "",
   url: "<?php echo SITE_SCRIPT_PATH;?>get_dashboard_tiles",
   beforeSend: function () {
      $(".right_con").css("min-height", "300px");
      $(".blockOverlay").css("background-color", "");
      $.blockUI();  //<---add this
  },
  complete: function () {
      //$(".right_con").unblock();
      $.unblockUI(); // <----and this
  },
  success: function (r) {
      $("#box_set").append(r);
      render_dashboard_tiles();
      lazyLoadTiles();
  }
});
```

Initialize it in `beforeSent` func

```
$.blockUI();
```

and unblock it in `complete` function with:

```
$.unblockUI();
```

Comment: Dude with my code blockUI is working but unblock is not..the code which you given showing two loader but do not unblock this..